# WP_Query and WooCommerce orders with pending status issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach, orders

I can't get order objects with status of wc-pending / Pending Payment. It simply returns ALL the order objects:

```
$my_course_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'   => 'wc-pending',
    'posts_per_page'      => -1
) );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Your code Is just working perfectly as expected, in frontend**, I have test it and **it output only orders with **pending status**. So I can't tell what is your issue as your question is not detailed.
>
> I have found this note on [WordPress WP_Query reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) that could be useful:
>   Note: [Ticket #18408](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408) For querying posts in the admin, consider using get_posts() as wp_reset_postdata() might not behave as expected.

In general, I don't use **`WP_Query()`** for customer orders but **`wc_get_orders()`** *(or `get_posts()` too)* this way:

```
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit'    => -1,
    'status'   => 'pending'
) );

// Iterating through each Order with pending status
foreach ( $customer_orders as $order ) {

    // Going through each current customer order items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
        $product_id = $item_values['product_id']; // product ID

        // Order Item meta data
        $item_meta_data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id );

        // Some output
        echo '<p>Line total for '.wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true ).'</p><br>';
    }
}
```

**This works also just to get the orders objects.**

Related documentation: [wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

Comment: Hi, Any idea how I can avoid getting `WC_Order_Refund` objects when using `wc_get_orders` ? Actually I am relying on a test inside the loop (ex: `$order->get_type() !=='shop_order_refund'`) but I am wondering if there is a better way using some *magic* inside the query

Comment: @TemaniAfif Add argument `type` like  `'type' => 'shop_order'` to avoid refund orders…

Comment: ok thanks, I Don't know how I missed this from the documentation -.- I was focusing on the status argument.

Answer (score 1):

> I fixed this weird issue by simply using custom query.

Somehow adding `'post_status' => 'wc-pending'` doesn't actually change the query, but if I use `'post_status' => 'pending'`, the query changes.

So what I did was using that custom query and modify `pending` to `wc-pending`.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the posters question!

For some reason when using WC_Order_Query you can't use prepended order status references.  So rather than 'wc-pending' you just need 'pending'.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue (returning ALL Orders) while debugging.

Wrapping the debug-code into an action helped outputting the expected data:

```
add_action( 'init', 'debug_init' );

function debug_init() {

    $custom_query_args = array(
        "fields" => "ids",
        "post_type" => "shop_order",
        "post_status" => array('wc-processing'),
        "posts_per_page" => "-1",
        "offset" => "0",
        "date_query" => [
                "before" => "2020-09-10 23:59",
                "after" => "1970-01-01 00:00",
                "inclusive" => "1"
        ],
        "order" => "DESC"
    );


    $debugQuery = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
    $order_ids   = $debugQuery->posts;

    print_r($order_ids);

    die();
}
```